# Vim freezes consistently for several reasons

Tags: vim

Vim freezes and I see a key sign as I have circled in the picture below when doing the following things

[image]

1. When opening a new file in terminal vim, especially a cpp file.
2. When terminal vim is left idle for a few seconds
3. When I click outside the terminal window and then click back into  terminal vim.

Ctrl-c unfreezes vim.

This is 100% reproducible on terminal vim, and not reproducible at all on MacVim. I am on MacOS.

When vim is launched from MacOS terminal app (and not iterm), I get a blinking key, and vim freezes just the same.

Please help me unfreeze vim, I've been digging for a while and not come up with anything.

Comment: Vim plugin git-gutter was causing this. I don’t yet know how to fix git-gutter, so I just commented it out for now, and at least my vim is back to functioning normally.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of your plugins/custom config is playing the devil here. Would you try and see if the same problem exists while running vim without any custom configurations, like :

```
vim --clean
```

if it works as expected, then you should definitely take a look into your .vimrc and start cleaning it.

If the error persists even after running vim clean, then what i would have done would be to check if the shell configs (like .bashrc,.bash_profile etc) for unwanted settings that directly/indirectly affect the working of vim.

As a last resort to avoid confusion, you should also try to debug whether you have given any custom setting for your terminal emulator. Try reinstalling your terminal emulator or run it clean and see if it helps.